# exclude weekends Jquery loop

Tags: jquery

I'm noob in Jquery and I'm working to show to customers in woocommerce The day of Delivery

I succeeded to do that by the code below

But I want to exclude weekends

How I can add a few lines to exclude weekends from my week to do Count++

```
$j('select[name=attribute_pa_choisissez-votre-delai]').change(function() {

            var d = new Date();
            var months = ["Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Août", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Décembre"];
            var days = ["Dimanche", "Lundi", "Mardi", "Mercredi", "Jeudi", "Vendredi", "Samedi"];

        if (this.value == 'j4') {
            document.getElementById("delai").show();
            d.setDate( d.getDate() + 4 );
            document.getElementById("delai").innerHTML = "Livraison prévue le : <span>" + days[d.getDay()] + " " + d.getDate() + " " + months[d.getMonth()] + "</span>";
        }
        else if (this.value == 'j3') {
            document.getElementById("delai").show();
            d.setDate( d.getDate() + 3 );
            document.getElementById("delai").innerHTML = "Livraison prévue le : <span>" + days[d.getDay()] + " " + d.getDate() + " " + months[d.getMonth()] + "</span>";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("delai").hide();
        }

    });
```

Comment: add if(d.getDay() != 0 && d.getDay() != 6) { .... }

Comment: Output still give me : Sunday 24 Novembre 2019

Comment: If you add my condition to IF after this.value == '..' && d.getDay() != 0 && d.getDay() != 6 so this must work

Comment: Output empty ! I need to add Count++ if Result give a weekend

Comment: which result? where is count? where you want to count? Please clarify your question, what you want.

Comment: I dont want to display to my customers a Weekend day.
I'm working with days[d.getDay()] d.getDate()  months[d.getMonth()]
If the output contains A weekend day. do d.getDate() ++++

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4);
while (d.getDay() === 6 || d.getDay() === 0)
    d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
```

to check if it's a weekend and add a day on as long as it's a weekend.

There are other options, eg you could check `d.getDay()` before the `+4` then add `+4/+5/+6` depending on the current day

Comment: Working for me ! Good job